# How do I suppress error messages from cp?

Tags: shell, wildcards, cp

I am currently looking ways to suppress error command in Linux, in particular, the command `cp`.

I do:

```
root@ubuntu:~$ cp /srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj ~/.
cp: cannot stat `/srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj': No such file or directory
```

How do I suppress the error message that gets **printed** on the screen? I.e., I don't want to see this error message in my monitor.

Comment: just FYI, best way to check for errors is exit codes. Piping STDERR to /dev/null is standard and will get rid of any visual indication of errors, but checking for a non zero return status will let you know if there was an error or not, at least that is how it is *supposed* to be...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to hide all error messages from cp? Or do you want to have no error message if the wildcard doesn't match any files? Or some other criteria?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

To suppress error output in `bash`, append `2>/dev/null` to the end of your command. This redirects filehandle 2 (STDERR) to `/dev/null`. There are similar constructs in other shells, though the specific construct may vary slightly.

Comment: Wonder why I never thought of that x.x

Comment: This might be also useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931510/ for those who want to suppress errors when assigning to a variable `var=$(errorcommand 2>/dev/null)`.

Answer (score 14):

Redirect the error message (STDERR) to `/dev/null`:

```bsh
root@ubuntu:~$ cp /srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj ~/. 2>/dev/null
```

Example:

```bsh
$ cp /srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj ~/.  ##Error message gets printed
cp: cannot stat ‘/srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj’: No such file or directory

$ cp /srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj ~/. 2>/dev/null  ##No error message gets printed
```

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not clear. The most sensible thing to do would be to not run `cp` at all when the wildcard doesn't match any file, rather than run `cp` and hide the error message.

To do that, if the shell is bash, set the [`nullglob` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) so that the wildcard pattern expands to nothing if it doesn't match any files. Then check whether the pattern expanded to anything, and don't call `cp` in that case.

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
files=(/srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj)
if [[ ${#files[@]} -ne 0 ]]; then
  cp "${files[@]}" ~
fi
```

In plain sh, test whether the glob was left unchanged, pointing to a non-existent file.

```
set -- /srv/ftp/201*/wha*/*.jj
if ! [ -e "$1" ] && ! [ -L "$1" ]; then
  cp "$@" ~
fi
```

Comment: This is the technique necessary if you don't want cp to throw an error from within a shell script -- or at least, I'm not an expert, but this is the one that seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use either:
1 option: `2>/dev/null`.
2 option: `2>&1`
Besides you can use this at the end of your command it will suppress the error messages:

Example here-

```
$cp nofile.txt b.txt > log.txt 2>/dev/null
```

here u can't retrieve any info about the error message.
Ex2:

```
$cp nofile.txt b.txt > log.txt 2>&1
```

here you can retrieve some info from the below log file:

```
$ cat log.txt
cp: cannot stat `nofile.txt': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in ~/.bashrc:

```
alias cp='cp 2> /dev/null'
```

then:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Recommending that this be done permanently seems silly to me. It seems like a much better idea to just pipe `stderr` to `/dev/null` when the error output is unwanted. Or using a different name than `cp`.

Comment: I agree with you but this is a solution for someone who doesn't want to see any error messages on his monitor for `cp`.

Comment: @M122 maybe the OP means "for this time", rather than permanently. If done as alias, then any copying that failed will be thought of as a success, which is not good.  It is like to not write the error handling for `cp`. If it is for one time to copy a folder where there are files in there that don't have the read permission and we don't want error messages to mess up the screen, that's another matter